# Open ball and continuity in metric space

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

I'm studying a bit of topology in metric space, and my text defines an open ball as follows : $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then an open ball centered at $x_0\in X$ is $B_{\epsilon}(x_0)=\{x\in X : d(x,x_0)<\epsilon\}\quad\epsilon>0$

Then we define continuity in metric space as follows : Let $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$ be two metric spaces and $f: X\to Y$. Then $f$ is said to be continuous at $x_0$ if

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta: d_{X}(x,x_0)<\delta\implies d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon $

Seeing this definition, I can't help but make a connection with the definition of continuity in $\mathbb{R}$, but in $\mathbb{R}$ whether the equality is strict or not doesn't change anything, yet in this definition it does. So if I want to take $X =Y= R$ and $d_{X} = d_{Y} = \lvert .\rvert$ I would have to be satisfied with a strict inequality and then I have the impression that something is missing.

Could someone help me better understand what's going on here please?

Thank you a lot

Comment: *Which* inequality can be strict or not? There are two inequalities in that definition of continuity.

Comment: How does strict or non-strict inequality make a difference here?

Comment: What JCS is getting at is the fact that it is no big deal if we have $\overline{B}_\delta(x_0) \subset f^{-1}\left(B_\epsilon(f(x_0))\right)$ because we still have $B_\delta(x_0) \subset \overline{B}_\delta(x_0)$.

Comment: The one in metric space is always strict from what I have seen so far, but in $\mathbb{R}$ I have always see a non-strict inequality. The difference is that if $\epsilon=5$ and $\delta=3$ for exemple, I did not end with the same sets $B_{\delta}(x_0)$ and $B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$, is this not a problem ? Or is there an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument that I ignores ?

Comment: @coboy Can you state precisely for which quantity you would like to have a large inequality? Is it on $\varepsilon$, on $\delta$, on $|x-x_0|$, on $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix a function $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, a point $x_0$, and consider the following properties:

> Property 1:
> $$
> \forall \varepsilon > 0,\exists \delta > 0,\quad |x-x_0|\leqslant \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant \varepsilon.
> $$
> Property 2:
> $$
> \forall \varepsilon > 0,\exists \delta > 0,\quad |x-x_0|< \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|< \varepsilon.
> $$

Let us show that these two properties are equivalent.

**Assume that property 1 holds.**
Fix $\varepsilon >0$.
By assumption applied on $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, there exists $\delta >0$, such that
$$
|x-x_0|\leqslant \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
In particular,
$$
|x-x_0| < \delta \implies |x-x_0|\leqslant \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|< \varepsilon,
$$
the last implication resulting on the fact that $0<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$.
Hence, we have proven property 2.

**Assume that property 2 holds.**
Fix $\varepsilon >0$.
By assumption, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
|x-x_0| < 2\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| <\varepsilon.
$$
Since $0<\delta <2 \delta$, it follows that
$$
|x-x_0| \leqslant \delta \implies |x-x_0| < 2\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant \varepsilon.
$$
The last inequality coming from the fact that if $a<b$, then $a\leqslant b$.
Hence, we have proven property 1.

---

The same ideas work for general metric spaces, since for $\varepsilon,\delta >0$, we have
$$
\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}
B_{\delta}(x_0) \subset \bar{B}_{\delta}(x_0)\subset B_{2\delta}(x_0) \quad \text{and} \quad \bar{B}_{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(f(x_0)) \subset B_{\varepsilon}(f(x_0)) \subset \bar{B}_{\varepsilon}(f(x_0)),
$$
and
$$
A\subset B \implies f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(B).
$$

The reason most authors choose to define continuity in terms of a strict inequality rather than a large inequality is because in a more general topological space, continuity is defined in terms of open subsets.

Comment: Thank you a lot Didier ! Your answer really makes sense !!